# UIButton Frame Not Resizing with Image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uibutton

I created a UIButton, using an image as the button. However, I am unable to resize the image/button. The code I am using is:

```
let leftArmImage = UIImage(named: "LeftArm") as UIImage?
let leftArmButton   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom) as UIButton
leftArmButton.frame = CGRect(x:self.view.center.x + 200,y:self.view.center.y,width:500,height:500)
leftArmButton.setImage(leftArmImage, for: .normal)
leftArmButton.imageView?.frame = leftArmButton.frame
leftArmButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PhysicalExam.bodyPartSingleTapped(_:)), for:.touchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(leftArmButton)
```

How can I resize the image?

Comment: Are you sure your button isn't already resizing, but the image just does not cover that area? Try pressing in the area where you think the button isn't, does it trigger an action? (Assuming you have attached an action to the button) Edit: What content mode is your image set to?

Comment: Instead of `leftArmButton.setImage()`, try to use `leftArmButton.setBackgroundImage()` so that it can cover whole button frame.

Comment: @Jerland2 The button is resizing, but the image is not. The button area correctly triggers the action. As far as the content mode of the image, I tried cycling through all three options and none of them filled the frame.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

**Programmatically**

```
button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
button.contentVerticalAlignment = .fill
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .fill
```

**Storyboard**

1. Open your Storyboard
2. Select button inside attribute inspector (Right side) -> In "Control" section -> select 4th option (last) for both Horizontal and Vertical Alignment.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of leftArmButton.setImage(), try to use leftArmButton.setBackgroundImage() so that it can cover whole button frame.

Comment: This still doesn't seem to fill the button frame. I made the frame visible so that I could verify this

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
leftArmButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

Comment: It says UIContentMode has no member 'aspectFill'

Comment: sorry I am not at my computer but i updated the answer. If it doesnt work, just type in a `.` and wait for xcode to popup options to autofill it to something wi AspectFill.

Comment: No problem. This was an option, but it did not resize the image